# How to read org-mode documentation inside Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I installed Emacs 24.3.1 (using `homebrew`), which already comes with `org-mode`, but I can't find the documentation for `org-mode` within the Emacs built-in documentation (accessible via `C-h i`).

I can find the `org-mode` docs online [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/index.html), but I'd prefer to read it directly in Emacs.

I find it very *strange* (in fact almost antithetical to the whole `org-mode` text orientation) to find myself having to read this documentation using a web browser, and not right inside Emacs.

Do I need to download and install this documentation separately in order to read it within Emacs?  If so, where can I find the appropriate (texinfo?) files?

Or is this documentation already bundled by default with Emacs (and I just need to configure my current Emacs installation to be able to browse it through `C-h i`)?

Comment: `f1 i`, `g`, `(org)`.

Comment: @abo-abo: thanks a lot!  i'd be happy to accept your comment as answer if you care to post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Call up the info with <kbd>C-h i</kbd>.
- Then call <kbd>g</kbd> (`Info-goto-node`).
- Enter `(org)` at the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Or `C-h o` with the following code in your `.emacs` file:

```
(with-eval-after-load "org"

  ;; Display the Org mode manual in Info mode.
  (define-key global-map (kbd "C-h o") 'org-info)) ; Not autoloaded!?
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write an autoload expression for that function, rather than only have the keybinding do anything if org is already loaded?

Comment: This key binding is one of many (I did not show the others), but, yes, IMO org-info should be autoloaded.

Comment: I meant that your answer could have comprised of an `(autoload ...)` expression followed by the `define-key` (or `global-set-key`) expression. If you wish something was autoloaded, you can fix that.

Comment: You're right (I did not understand your suggestion); that's another possibility. However, same amount of lines ;-)

Comment: @phils: I'm intrigued by your suggestion, but I can't fill in the  `...` in your "`(autoload ...)`" reference.  BTW, since abo-abo's answer worked for me, I conclude that the `org-mode` documentation *is* included in my Emacs installation, but I still don't understand why it does not show in the menu I get when I press `C-h i` (or `C-h i d`).  Is there some configuration code I could add to my `~/.emacs` that would add an item for `org-mode` to this menu?

Comment: The info menus come from the `dir` files in the info directories. You might use `C-h i g (org) RET` then `C-x d RET` to check for a `dir` file which might be expected to have an Org Mode entry. Mine reads "* Org Mode: (org).              Outline-based notes management and organizer", but offhand I'm not sure exactly how that gets populated normally.

Comment: Regarding autoloads, see `C-h f autoload`. The `org-info` function is defined in the `org.el` library, so you could use `(autoload 'org-info "org" "Read documentation for Org-mode in the info system." t)`

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the Org mode documentation as others like **abo-abo** have described, you are all set. Read on if you still don't find it.

In your running emacs, look at the variable **Info-directory-list**. It's value may look somethng like this:

```
("/home/myself/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20141222" "/usr/share/info/emacs-24" "/usr/share/info/" "/usr/share/info/")
```

The point here is there should be a directory which contains the Org mode documentation. Here it is the directory *"/home/myself/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20141222"*. You can look in that directory for a file called **dir** - which describes info files in this directory. In dir, a line like:

```
* Org Mode: (org).      Outline-based notes management and organizer
```

says there is an info node describing *Org Mode*, and the top of that node is in the file **org**, in that directory. So you should make sure that file is in the directory.